# How to convert floating number into percentage format and save into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

By searching around, I learned that mysql does not have a native way to format number as percentage. So, can we do it in php and save it into mysql table? I would like to learn how.

Comment: You do know that its just dividing the float by 100, right?

Comment: yes. Do you mean I wait till I need to display the numbers to do the converting job?

Comment: Well, storing floats in the db, then converting them before displaying would be better if you want to keep the accuracy of the floats for future purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Take the percentage, divide by 100, and store the resulting number (which should be a float) in your MySQL database, in a float datafield. 
That is the only conversion Yu need. Percentages are unknown for computers, they are a way of formatting and interpretation.

Comment: I already have the floating numbers, just think to store it as percentage format. Since it can't be done, I will just leave it as it is. Thanks!